# Getting wrong exception response (403)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a login controller, which if credentials are bad - should return BadCredentialsException with the message in json, but in stead of this I get 403 response.

My code:

Controller -

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> login(@Valid @RequestBody AuthenticationRequest data) {
    try {

        System.out.println(data);
        String email = data.getEmail();
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, data.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String token = jwtTokenProvider.createToken(email);
        AuthenticationResponse response = new AuthenticationResponse(email, token);
        return ok(response);
    } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException(messageSource.getMessage("authController.invalidCredentials", null, null));
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig -

```
http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider))
                .and()
                .cors().and().csrf()
                .disable();
```

Token creation -

```
    public String createToken(String username) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(username);

        Date now = new Date();
        Date validity = new Date(now.getTime() + validityInMilliseconds);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(validity)
                .signWith(HS256, secretKey)
                .compact();
    }
```

Current Json I get is -

```
    {
        "timestamp": "2021-03-14T23:34:49.038+00:00",
        "status": 403,
        "error": "Forbidden",
        "message": "",
        "path": "/auth/login/"
    }
```

The goal is to get the message in the json, that something is bad with the credentials. Thanks a lot for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the default Authentication entry point is `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint`

You could override the default authentication entry point like this:

```
public static class Message {
    private String message;

    public Message(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}

private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // set your authentication entry point
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED); // you could replace your custom HTTP status
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Message(authException.getMessage())));
        out.flush();
    });

    http
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()

            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider))
            .and()
            .cors().and().csrf()
            .disable();
}
```

You also can check the exception type:

```
    if (authException instanceof BadCredentialsException) {
        // Do somthing
    }
```

Comment: But could you explain why this is not working by default? why do we need to do those config changes.. Thanks again :)

Comment: You could check the WebSecurityConfiguration for more information. `WebSecurityConfiguration` use `WebSecurity` builder to create a Filter chain that performs the security. Your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is a cutomization for the `WebSecurity`. Move on the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#getHttp`, it create an Exception handling (ExceptionHandlingConfigurer) on method `applyDefaultConfiguration` by calling `http.exceptionHandling();`

`ExceptionHandlingConfigurer` create the filter `ExceptionTranslationFilter` for handling `AuthenticationException` .

Comment: Look in the `ExceptionHandlingConfigurer#configure`, you can see it create `ExceptionTranslationFilter` with default entry point `Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint`. The `ExceptionTranslationFilter` handle `AuthenticationException` by method `handleSpringSecurityException`. And the `BadCredentialsException` is an `AuthenticationException`. That why you've got 403 if your not set an entry point for the `ExceptionTranslationFilter`

Comment: You could use the debugger for better understand.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

SecurityConfig

```
            http
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/auth/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider))
            .and()
            .cors().and().csrf()
            .disable()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());;
```

Comment: Hey, sorry but you example did not work out. Maybe you can specify your answer? What is that securityConfigurerAdapter?

Comment: Your http request url "/auth/login" has not been filter by the SecurityConfig,so you should update the code.